What does it mean: Unity is canceling the Runtime Fee
There was today an announcement from Unity that they are canceling the runtime fee (besides some other changes to the payment model). But the article itself does not mention what the runtime fee is/ was.

The Unity Runtime Fee was a new charge that applies to eligible games based on their performance metrics. This fee was calculated based on either a percentage of the game's revenue or the number of initial engagements, whichever was lower.
In 2023 they introduced a runtime fee with

starting January 1, 2024, the company will adopt a "per-install" fee
system, activated once specific revenue and install thresholds are
hit. To break it down: Unity Personal and Plus users will face a $0.20
fee per install after their game achieves $200,000 in annual revenue
and 200,000 lifetime installs.

They reverted the changes and the new pricing model can now be found with all changes at their support page

The fee had already been changed to a percentage model.

@JackAidley want to propose a clarifying edit?

Many systems for creating software include a runtime library that is necessary for the software created to work. Some examples of this would be the Common Language Runtime used for .NET, or the CRT required by Microsoft Visual Studio if you use any of the C++ standard library functions. A runtime fee in its most general sense is simply a charge applied in order to use this runtime.
Unity, like other popular engines, has always included a runtime which supports a great many of the Engine's functions but unlike it's biggest competitor (Unreal), Unity had chosen to license the Runtime for free and charge a per-seat annual subscription for users with revenue above a certain threshold instead. They'd also previously claimed the lack of a percentage fee as a distinguishing factor between themselves and Unreal.
Following it's public listing in 2020, and several rounds of lay-offs in 2022 and 2023, Unity decided that it needed to increase revenue and rather than taking the more obvious route of charging a percentage of revenue in the manner of Unreal it announced in September 2023 that it would charge a $0.20 fee per install for developers above an install threshold. This was called the Runtime Fee. Additionally, rather than applying this fee only from forthcoming versions, they announced it would apply to all Unity versions from January 1st, 2024 - thus retroactively altering the conditions for existing games and developers.
This was met with an immediate backlash, some of this coming from developers making free games for which a $0.20 fee per install would have been a larger amount than they made from the games, and some outraged at finding the terms changed retroactively. There swiftly followed a boycott of Unity's Ad platform from a number of developers, which would immediately hit Unity's bottom line.
As a result of this they swiftly backtracked, apologised, and announced a new version of the Runtime Fee two weeks later. This revised policy meant no fee would apply to games made with the Personal Tier, that install numbers would be self-reported (they'd previously claimed they could know this number in some unclear way, which was interpreted by some to mean mandatory analytics), that the new policy would only apply from Unity 6, and that all fees would be capped to 2.5% of the game's revenue.
This all caused massive reputational damage to Unity, and many developers moved away from Unity as result. Subsequently the CEO responsible resigned shortly afterwards and the company went through multiple rounds of lay-offs. After a time under an interim CEO, the company appointed Matthew Bromberg as its new CEO.
Finally, in September 2024 almost a year after the initial introduction of the Runtime Fee, it was dropped completely, alongside an announcement of significant increases in the annual per-seat costs of using the engine for larger customers.

I would suggest trimming or excising the first paragraph. It seems so off-topic that I thought this was an AI-generated answer at first.

@Kevin I think it provides necessary context.
